synthesis does not reduce gates in rtl viewer on my systemverilog design file in quartus prime lite 23.1
I compile the silly function f(a,b,c) = sum minterms(0,4,5) in systemverilog design file
and the netlist rtl viewer shows me a weird gate schematic ~a&~b&~c + (a&~b)&c + (a&~b)&c
instead of displaying the proper reduced gate schematic ~b&~c + a&~b. I don't know why this weird overcomplex result. I admit I'm just beginning but I dismay when following the book the result doesn't look like the expected one at all. (By the way the book is Digital Design and Computer Architecture by Harris and Harris).

sorry the sillyfunction is  ~a & ~b & ~c | a & ~b & ~c |a & ~b & c;

The correct result is   ~b & ~c | a & ~b in gate schematic, you know. But in my case the rtl viewer is weird and even more complex than the original funtion in my systemverilog file.

The purpose of FPGA synthesis is to map the behavior expressed in RTL code onto the targeted physical device's primitive cells. Xilinx calls these CLBs (configurable logic blocks), Altera calls them ALM's (Advanced Logic Module).  They often consist of a couple of 4-6 variable look up tables, and corresponding flip flops. Sometimes the CLB's are grouped in a group of 2 or 4 and called a slice.  The fancier the device is the more complicated the 'CLB' or 'ALM'.  Sometimes the LUT portion of the primitive cell is available as a small distributed memory.
You have modeled RTL coded at gate level, mapped the gates to logic cells using synthesis, and are expecting to see gates again.
In the post synthesis schematic viewer, the tool will try to represent the configuration of the primitive cell in some understandable way, buts its not designed to give a nice looking textbook equivalent gate level picture in all cases.
There are cases where the tool will show a clean schematic which looks like  gates.  For example if your logic optimizes down to just a single AND or OR function it will likely show that.  Don't expect to enter an arbitrary sum of products or product of sums, and have it show the textbook optimization of gates like you are circling boxes in a K-map.
The tool will optimize the representation using the primitives available in the targeted hardware.
Physical hardware FPGA's do not consist of a sea-of-gates.
The post map schematic will look different across different FPGA vendors, device families, and maybe even different versions of the same tool.
If you have modeled a three variable logic function and see three input wires and one output wire attached to one level of logic (a single CLB) in the schematic viewer, then the tool probably did its job.
If you have doubt the synthesis results you can

Run a post synthesis simulation
Target hardware in the lab

to verify the synthesis result.

Thanks a lot, Mikef. I am ignorant, just beginning and now I understand that the tool uses the resources available for the particular FPGA (in this case a Cyclone IV E). I brooded about the tool might not represent properly the k-map reduced schematic to no avail I see. I AM SATISFIED.
